# how to show that sin(x) is not continuous with this topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topology on $\Bbb R$ with basis $\{[a,b):a<b, \  a,b\in \Bbb R\}$. 
Could anyone give a hint to show that the function $f:\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is not continuous? Here, the domain and codomain equipped with the same (given) topology. Thanks!

Comment: are the domain and codomain equipped with same topology?

Comment: Yes! The domain and codomain equipped with the same topology.

Comment: I'd look for an open set whose preimage is not open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can look at the preimage by $\sin$ of the open $[1,2)$. You get $\pi /2 + 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$ which is not open.

Comment: Very clever !!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence {$ \pi +\frac{1}{n}$} which converges to $\pi$ in this topology but {$sin(\pi +\frac{1}{n})$} does not converge to $sin(\pi)=0$ w.r.t. this topology since there is a basic nbd of 0 which does not contain any negative.